# PyAutoGUI Mac generator object _locateAll_opencv at 0x7fe8faab6eb0

Tags: python

I use PyAutoGUI to Locate image on my screen then I got this number (generator object _locateAll_opencv at 0x7fe8faab6eb0) instead x and y number?

Comment: what code did you use?

Comment: function `locate_all` searchs all matching objects and it may gives generator which you could use with for-loop to process all found images `for item in locate_all(...): ...`

Answer (score 0):

Word `all` means it search all matching object - and for many results it may have to give generator or list with all objects (even if it found one item). And both can be used with `for`-loop to process all found objects.

```
for item in locateAll(...):
    process_item(item)
    x, y, width, height = item
    print(x, y, width, height)
```

or

```
all_items = list( locateAll(...) )

process_first_item( all_items[0] )
process_last_item( all_items[-1] )

for item in all_items:
    process_item(item)
    x, y, width, height = item
    print(x, y, width, height)
```